# InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block ,on UNIQUE constraint

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I tried to get executed with my `except:` statement... while attempt to oppose the functionality of UNIQUE constraint..But ended with exceptional error..
The Postgresql database table already contains the row that I have used in

> db.insert("The News","AparnaKumar",1995,234569654)

but it works well on inserting unrepeated rows..

```
import psycopg2
class database:

    def __init__(self):

        self.con=psycopg2.connect("dbname='book_store' user='postgres' password='5283' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
        self.cur=self.con.cursor()
        self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists books(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,author TEXT NOT NULL,year integer NOT NULL,isbn integer NOT NULL UNIQUE)")
        self.con.commit()

    def insert(self,title,author,year,isbn):
      try:
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO books(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(title,author,year,isbn))
        self.con.commit()
      except:
          print("already exists..")

    def view(self):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
        rows=self.cur.fetchall()
        print(rows)

    def search(self,title=None,author=None,year=None,isbn=None):
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE title=%s or author=%s or year=%s or isbn=%s",(title,author,year,isbn))
        row=self.cur.fetchall()
        print(row)

db=database()
db.insert("The News","AparnaKumar",1995,234569654)
db.view()
db.search(year=1995)
```

[image: InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block]

Answer (score 8):

You can either modify your python function to rollback the transaction, or modify the sql to not insert a new row if a conflict occurs (postgresql versions 9.5+):

option 1:

```
def insert(self,title,author,year,isbn):
  try:
    self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO books(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    self.con.commit()
  except:
    self.con.rollback()
      print("already exists..")
```

option 2 (works for postgresql versions 9.5 or later):

```
def insert(self,title,author,year,isbn):
  try:
    self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO books(title,author,year,isbn) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING",(title,author,year,isbn))
    self.con.commit()
  except:
      print("already exists..")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SAVEPOINT`.

See the second question in the [psycopg FAQ list](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep an transaction open, you should use a SAVEPOINT and ROLLBACK to that SAVEPOINT when the exception occurs. But since you use a catchall exception (too broad), this will also happen on other errors. So it gets a bit out of control.

Perhaps a very simple solution is to check using a SELECT if the record you're about to insert already exists.